# Porque un evento en JavaScript se dispara solo:

Tags: javascript, eventos

la primera parte viene del index.html

cuando se carga la pagina, aparece en automatico el mensaje en la consola.
esta es la parte del app.js

```
<div id='tools2'>
        <button id='loadProject'></button>
 </div>


const ButtonLoadProject = document.getElementById('loadProject');

ButtonLoadProject.addEventListener('click', Load1Project());

function Load1Project(){
    console.log('Subir proyecto2');
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Eso pasa porque no estás pasando la función, sino que la estás ejecutando y lo que devuelve la función es lo que pasas como callback. Solo debes usar el nombre de la función sin paréntesis al final.

```
ButtonLoadProject.addEventListener('click', Load1Project);
```